# iOS swift3 equivalent of "RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding"

Tags: ios, encryption, swift3, cryptography

I am getting decryption error on sever when I used SwiftyRSA to encrypt a text using publicKey on client.

I have referred this 
[RSA: encrypt in iOS, decrypt in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108672/rsa-encrypt-in-ios-decrypt-in-java) but this is for SHA1.

I am using https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA library.

`kSecPaddingOAEP` and `RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding` works. But how Can I make it work for `RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding`

```
let str = "Clear Text"
let clear = try ClearMessage(string: str, using: .utf8)    
let encrypted = try clear.encrypted(with: publicKey, padding: .OAEP)
```

I want to encrypt data in swift3 without touching server code.

Comment: Do you need the Java code to decrypt?

Comment: I want to encrypt data in swift3 without touching server code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Apple's security framework, it does not support OAEP padding with a SHA256 hash digest, but it can be done through the OpenSSL library. 
https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone